# Formio Checkbox Validation - Max number of selections

Tags: validation, formio

Form.io question here.

Has anyone worked out how to apply a count check on checkbox fields.

I'd like the user to only be able to choose up to 3 fields.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do this, It works with the following code:

```
valid = countIn(Object.values(input));
function countIn(array){

var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
    if(array[i] == true)
        count++;
};

if (count <= 3){
  return true
}
else{
  return false

}

}

}
```